# Insert column data rows (all) in another column table where each row matches the common ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

```
Table1                                      Table2
column1ID | column1                 column2ID |    column2
     1    |   A                          1    |    copyofA
     2    |   B                          2    |    copyofB
```

As requested i want to insert in table2 the copyofA copyofB rows etc (around 54k rows) but column2ID has to match column1ID that is already populated.

As per title i want to Insert column data rows (all of them) in another column table where each row matches the common ID column value

I used the usual command

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column2)
SELECT column1
FROM table1
```

but unfortunately it seems that the column with the ID value needs some sort of comparing in order to be successful

Output Error

```
[Err] ERROR:  insert or update on table "table2" violates foreign key constraint "table2_column2ID_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (column2ID)=(400992) is not present in table "table2".
```

Last to add that table2 obviously has a foreign key attached to the primary key ID of table1

Comment: Show both tables defination with keys, primary keys, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want an `update`:

```
update table2 t2
    set column2 = t1.column1
    from table1 t1
    where t2.id = t1.id
```